# Changing text color for Link widget

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am trying to set a specific color to a SWT widget **org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link**, but I am not able to override the default color.

Is there a way to change the default color **RGB (0, 51, 153)** to any specific color.

Answer (score 3):

`Link.setForeground` sets the normal text color, the actual link color can't be set and uses the OS defaults.

The Forms controls `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Hyperlink` and `ImageHyperlink` used in conjunction with `HyperlinkGroup` do allow the colors (and underlining) to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `Label`?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Label link = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    link.setText("http://www.google.co.uk");
    link.setToolTipText("http://www.google.co.uk");
    link.setCursor(display.getSystemCursor(SWT.CURSOR_HAND));
    link.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
    link.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            Program.launch(link.getText());
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I can't do that becasue I want it to be underlined. Can you think of a way to have a clickable (cursor changes) underlined piece of text that is coloured in white?